# Writing JTable into Excel

Tags: java, excel, swing, apache-poi, jexcelapi

I am planning to move the contents of a JTable into a Microsoft Excel sheet. The Excel sheet should have some format specifications. For instance if a column has a value 'A' it should be green in colour. If it is 'B' red in colour.

I am in analysis stage. Which Jar should I use? The data is not huge.Performance is not a big concern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend Apache POI. It is easy to use, allows styling, etc. See the quick guide [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative could be [JExcelAPI](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) - I've used this and found it excellent.